# How to constrain a JSON field by a few possible values?

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I have a field "type1" that can only have values of "1", "7" or "9". What should I add to my schema so that the requirement of only these 3 values is fullfilled?
The "type1" has this structure right now:

```
"type1": {
    "type": String, 
    "pattern": "^[0-9]+$",
    "maxLength": 1

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define it as `enum` to make it more simple and easier to read:

```
"type1": { "enum": [ "1", "7", "9" ] }
```

See also: [Understanding JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html#enumerated-values)

Comment: that would be a nice solution, but we're using draft-04. I'll mark it as an accepted answer by the end of the next day.
I decided to use "oneOf", doesn't look nice but works.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that. "oneOf" is also fine in this case.

Comment: `enum` is a valid keyword in draft-04.  https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.5.1